# Adding hours (x) in a given unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I have the following function using moment which checks the difference in minutes from a given UNIX timestamp. `actualStartTime is in unix format (for e.g 1599226113699)`

```
const endTime = moment(offer.data.actualStartTime, "x")
  if (endTime.diff(now, "minutes") <= 15 && snapshot.key) {
    remindersSentKeys.push(snapshot.key)
}
```

Unix timestamp is stored in `offer.data.actualStartTime`. My problem is I need to add another field `duration: number` which adds hours in the `endTime` variable and return in the moment format.

```
const finalEndTime = moment(offer.data.actualStartTime, "x") + *offer.data.duration*
```

For e.g if `duration is 4`. The variable `finalEndTime` should add an additional 4 hours in the `actualStartTime` and then check the 15 min difference.

Comment: That's not a Unix time- its a Javascript time. They have the same datum but the former counts in seconds and the latter in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This will add `duration` hours to the existing time

```
moment().add({hours: duration})
```

For your case

```
const finalEndTime = moment(offer.data.actualStartTime, "x").add({hours: offer.data.duration});
```